# Get the substring value of a table with delimiter count

Tags: mysql, csv, substring

I've a tableA with 2 columns (value1, value2) with a CSV formatted value. I want to create a tableB with the same fields as tableA but, in those 2 columns, with just a limit number of values (note that I don't know how many characters exists between commas). This "limit" is the first *n* elements of the CSV.

**Table A**

```
+----+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| id |   other  |        value1        |        value2        |
+----+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1  |  other1  | 111,222,333,444      | 1616,17,1,8,19,2020  |
| 2  |  other2  | 55,6,7777,8,9        | 21,22,23             |
| 3  |  other3  | 10101,11.11,13,14,15 | 242424,2525,26,27    |
+----+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

**Table B (limit to 3 elements)**

```
+----+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| id |   other  |        value1        |        value2        |
+----+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1  |  other1  | 111,222,333          | 1616,17,1            |
| 2  |  other2  | 55,6,7777            | 21,22,23             |
| 3  |  other3  | 10101,11.11,13       | 242424,2525,26       |
+----+----------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

### EDITED:

I didn't mention that those tables have a huge number of elements (and many other columns like "other"). Therefore I prefer to use:

```
create table tableB LIKE tableA; 
INSERT tableB SELECT * FROM tableA;
```

and then update the value1 and value2 (in 2 distinct transactions - in fact I've 91 columns like that). This probably is more efficient then a "create table" with all the values inside in a single query...

---

### EDITED2 (solution):

**SQLFiddle:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e73a/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cam use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function, together with [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-select.html):

```
CREATE TABLE TableB
  SELECT id,
         other,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(value1, ',', 3) AS value1,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(value2, ',', 3) AS value2
  FROM   TableA
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3de9/1/0).

Comment: Is there a way to treat the CSV as a table and then select the number of columns to be used, again, as a group_concat? I know that your answer is exactly what I need (many thks for that!).. just wondering...

Comment: @kairos: So then do what you suggest... `CREATE TABLE`, then `UPDATE`.

Comment: @kairos: `UPDATE TableB SET value1 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(value1, ',', 3), value2 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(value2, ',', 3);`